# Android Studio import Google Play Services project refresh failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services

currently I'm trying to import the Google Play Services for my Android project which is created using Android Studio. Now, I read the part where I should start from [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) and since this one is still using Eclipse I ended up in [these](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) steps. Now upon adding the Google Play Services on my app I receive an error saying:

> Gradle 'MyApp' project refresh failed:
>              Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77.
>              Required by:
>              MyApp:myapp:unspecified

So I tried changing the versions on this line:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'

into:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+',
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4+', 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.+',
```

so on but still getting the same error (only the version changes).

As for reference my Android Studio Version is currently @ 0.5.2 (I cant update yet)
Grade ver 0.9.+.

And the screenshot of my installed packages in Android SDK Manager:

[image]

Now I'm wondering where exactly my problem is. And additionally I don't want to download a JAR file of the Google Play Services to solve this. I want to stick on the official way for implementing this in Android Studio. :D

Comment: is google Repository in the extras installed??If not then install it and restart android studio.

Comment: There is no Google Repository or Android Repository appears on my SDK Manager. Only the Android Support Repository which is already installed. And I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are you sure you have updated your SDK Tools,SDK Platform Tools,SDK Build Tools from the Tools section??

Comment: I have both of it but in a bit lower version of Rev. 22.6.3 and 19.0.2 respectively. I guess it should not be the cause of this problem.

Comment: try updating it maybe it might be causing the problem

Comment: As I highlight the compile line I found out that the Android Repository is really the main reason why since it mentioned that it is not installed. On the otherhand in SDK Manager. I can't find it anywhere on the extras.

Comment: Also you have to update your studio to v0.8.6 and your gradle to 0.12.+

Comment: Aaand finally. Yep it works as I updated my SDK tools and SDK platform. Then after that the Google Repo appears and I just installed it together with the updated Play Store Services and it works! (Just changed min SDK from 8 to 9)

As for the AS and Gradle version. There is no need to update those two. But will update it for sure some other time.

Comment: @goonerdroid hope you post the steps as the correct answer so I can tag it and thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install `Google Repository` from the SDKManager.If you can't find `Google Repository` then update your `SDK Tools`,`SDK Platform Tools`,`SDK Build Tools` from the Tools section